# process.env.NODE_ENV not being read correctly by express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

Even though I have set:

```
export NODE_ENV=production
```

in `.bashrc` file which is not getting overwritten by any other file,

The value of `process.env.NODE_ENV` inside app.js is undefined whereas value of `app.get('env')` is development.

Again, I am able to print the value of NODE_ENV correctly to console by using:
`echo $NODE_ENV` which returns production.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Worth checking what `process.env` looks like. Is your Node process being launched from a login shell, or via some other mechanism like `cron`?

Comment: open up node.js console and type "process.env" this will display all the env variables on your current system.  You may also need to restart your system or explorer if you just added the variable.

Answer (score 0):

A good way of setting environment variables is via the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package. All the variables set via dotenv are accessible inside process.env